# How to programmatically query firebase conversion data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've got Google Firebase data flowing into Google Analytics.  What API or programmatic query can I use to get conversion data from Firebase or Analytics?  Recently I linked the data into Bigquery but I haven't started looking at it yet.  Is Bigquery my only option?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use BigQuery to get data programmatically from Firebase or GA4.